# Django 1.11 best to approach to "quarter" logic for multiple purposes

Tags: django, datetime, django-1.11

I have a Survey app that includes a Survey model and a Response model.

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    is_published = models.BooleanField()

class Response(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, related_name="responses")
```

I also have an *admin* view for displaying all users, and displaying the latest *response* a user has submitted

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'latest_response')

    def latest_response(self, obj):
        return obj.response_set.latest('created')
```

I only have one Survey which I will release for Response every quarter.

Currently, the UserAdmin view's latest_response returns the **name** of the Survey (charField).

What I would like to do is use the Response's **created** or **updated** (whichever is latest) and, in the UserAdmin, display this as "Q1 2018" for example.

I know this can be achieved relatively easily through Django 2.0 using the Date Function extract, but how would I do this using Django 1.11?

Comment: "Q%d %d" %(((dt.month-1)//3)+1, dt.year) where dt is the datetime instance.

Comment: Thanks, works. I inserted the following into my class Response(models.Model) object:     def __str__(self):
        msg = u"Q%d %d" %(((self.created.month-1)//3)+1, self.created.year)
        return msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.x you can use the following logic,

```
"Q%d %d" %(((self.created.month-1)//3)+1, self.created.year)
```